# Merge two queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help in to merge this 2 queries, I have try using `UNION` and get error for the result

-- First Query

```
select  p.pegawainama,r.pegawainid, sum(cast(round(r.besarpotongan,0) as int)) as totalpotnondinas 
from 
    rpotongan r
inner join 
    pegawai p on p.pegawainid=r.pegawainid
where 
    r.nojenpot not in (1,7,6,12,14)
    --and r.pegawainid = '6290134A'
    and r.bulan = '3'
    and r.tahun = '2012'
    and p.kodebayar = '152012'
group by
    r.pegawainid,
    p.pegawainama
order by
    p.pegawainama,
    sum(cast(round(r.besarpotongan,0) as int))
```

-- Second Query

```
select p.pegawainama, r.pegawainid, sum(cast(round(r.besarpotongan,0) as int)) as totalpotdinas from rpotongan r 
inner join 
    pegawai p on p.pegawainid=r.pegawainid
where 
    r.nojenpot in (1,7,6,12,14)
    --and r.pegawainid = '6290134A'
    and r.bulan = '3'
    and r.tahun = '2012'
    and p.kodebayar = '152012'
group by
    r.pegawainid,
    p.pegawainama
order by
    p.pegawainama,
    sum(cast(round(r.besarpotongan,0) as int))
```

Comment: Hard to say without the error, but I'm betting on the RDBMS complaining that you're using `ORDER BY` in a `UNION` without enclosing the union components in `()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `UNION`, you need to have the same column names, so you can't have `totalpotnondinas` in one query and `totalpotdinas` in the other.

What you can do is call both columns `totals` and add an additional column that indicates which query was the source of the data. For example:

```
select p.pegawainama,r.pegawainid, sum(cast(round(r.besarpotongan,0) as int)) as total,
'potnondinas' as src from rpotongan r inner join pegawai p on p.pegawainid=r.pegawainid 
where r.nojenpot not in (1,7,6,12,14) --and r.pegawainid = '6290134A' and r.bulan = '3'
and r.tahun = '2012' and p.kodebayar = '152012' group by r.pegawainid, p.pegawainama
order by p.pegawainama, sum(cast(round(r.besarpotongan,0) as int))
```

-- Second Query

```
select p.pegawainama, r.pegawainid, sum(cast(round(r.besarpotongan,0) as int)) as total, 
'potdinas' as src from rpotongan r inner join pegawai p on p.pegawainid=r.pegawainid
where r.nojenpot in (1,7,6,12,14) --and r.pegawainid = '6290134A' and r.bulan = '3'
and r.tahun = '2012' and p.kodebayar = '152012' group by r.pegawainid, p.pegawainama
order by p.pegawainama, sum(cast(round(r.besarpotongan,0) as int))
```

If you omit the synthetic `src` column, `UNION` will merge identical results.

Comment: Thank you for replies, i have got it. but I wonder how if i want to make potnondinas and potdinas in a different column because if we use union all column potnondinas and potdinas will store in one column.

Comment: In the query with `potnondinas`, add `null as potdinas` and in the query with `potdinas` add `null as potnondinas`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how these are two different queries except for the different alias, but you can only have one `ORDER BY` in a `UNION` (the error message should have told you exactly that). Try:

```
select  p.pegawainama,r.pegawainid, sum(cast(round(r.besarpotongan,0) as int))
     as totalpotnondinas 
from 
    rpotongan r
inner join 
    pegawai p on p.pegawainid=r.pegawainid
where 
    r.nojenpot not in (1,7,6,12,14)
    --and r.pegawainid = '6290134A'
    and r.bulan = '3'
    and r.tahun = '2012'
    and p.kodebayar = '152012'
group by
    r.pegawainid,
    p.pegawainama
union all
select p.pegawainama, r.pegawainid, sum(cast(round(r.besarpotongan,0) as int))
    as totalpotnondinas 
from 
    rpotongan r 
inner join 
    pegawai p on p.pegawainid=r.pegawainid
where 
    r.nojenpot in (1,7,6,12,14)
    --and r.pegawainid = '6290134A'
    and r.bulan = '3'
    and r.tahun = '2012'
    and p.kodebayar = '152012'
group by
    r.pegawainid,
    p.pegawainama
order by
    pegawainama,
    totalpotnondinas;
```

If you want the `SUM()` column to be decipherable between the two results, use `SUM... AS col1, NULL AS col2` in the first query, and `NULL AS col1, SUM... AS col2` in the second.